# Updating jar manifest file - java.io.IOException: invalid manifest format

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, manifest

I need to update the manifest in my jar file that I create (export) within Eclipse.  I've tried to follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/secman.html) explanation without success.  I'm not quite sure what to specify on the command line.  The Oracle web site is not too clear. I then found a post on SO that said to extract the manifest.mf file from the jar archive, update it, and add it back to the jar archive.  I've tried that too, and it appears to work, however, at runtime, I get `java.io.IOException: invalid manifest format`.  What is the correct way to update the **manifest.mf** to add new attributes?  An example would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links offered by Peter were partially useful.  However, I was able to solve this more or less by trial and error.  The Oracle docs that explain how to do this need lots of work.  They lack a good example of how to proceed.  Anyway, for those who run into the same issues, here's what I did.  I created a text file (eg. "Manifest.txt") using Notepad that contains the manifest attributes I wanted to add/update.  In creating this file, I made sure to add a new line character to the last line by pressing the  key on the keyboard.  Next, I created a DOS bat file to do the actual modification.  Here's what it looked like...

```
echo Updating manifest permissions...
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\jar" -umf "c:\some folder\Manifest.txt" "C:\some folder\jartoupdate.jar"
```

The order of the jar arguments as they relate to the actual paths that follow on the command line is important.  The links from Peter's reply pointed that part out.

Answer (score 4):

As manifest file is contained in META-INF subdirectory of jar file under the name MANIFEST.MF .Whenever you create a jar file for command prompt by the command 
**jar cvf Jarfilename FilesToadd** 
Then a default manifest file is created.
One can view this file and get an idea of valid Manifestfile.
In order to extract manifest file from jar type following command in cmd 
**jar xvf Jarfilename** now a META-INF subdirectory will appear in the base directory from here you can view default manifest file.
Sometimes while updating manifest file we get  **java.io.IOException: invalid manifest format**.This error comes because of following reasons:

1.You may have not left space between the name and value of any section in manifest file,
like **Version:1.1** is inavalid section instead write **Version: 1.1** that space between colon and 1.1 really matters a lot.

2.While specifying the main class you might have added .class extension at the end of class name.Simply specify the main class by typing **Main-Class: Classname**.

3.You may have not added newline at the end of file.You need not to write \n for specifying newline instead just leave the last line of your manifest file blank that will serve the purpose

4.Your text file for manifest must use **UTF-8** encoding otherwise you may get into some trouble.

Finally i am providing an example of what a manifest file must look like.
Here package is calculator and the main class is Calculator.java

Manifest-Version: 2.1

Created-By: UselessCoder

Package-Name: calculator

Class-Name: calculator.Calculator.java

Main-Class: calculator.Calculator

Answer (score 1):

*java.io.IOException: invalid manifest format* error is also thrown when,

> unwanted empty lines are present in manifest file.

For example:

**Before**  *manifest.txt*

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Main-Class: Sample
```

**After** *manifest.txt*

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Sample
```

Answer (score 0):

When modifying the contens of a jar you should more look into this direction: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html and especially 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html which describes the process  
 of updating the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

To update a manifest in a jar file, you found the answer in the oracle docs. Here is another place to see the answer. Assuming you have read access to the directory where the JDK is installed and the documentation was downloaded with it (easy to download the documentation, this is for SE7  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html):

1. go to the *[install_directory]/docs*. In there is an *index.html* file. 

    >>>>    e.g. mine for JDK 6 is called *C:\my_TOOLS\Java_stuff\jdk_1.6.0_20\docs\index.html*
2. Drag *index.html* onto a browser page.
3. That page shows you an overview of the JDK documentation and has many links to useful information. 
   [image: JDK 6]
   In the top box's row under the Java Language row, click on JAR. It takes you to the page summarizing the documentation (with links) of the jartool. 

   In the "JAR Tools" section of that page, click on the reference page link for your platform (you probably want "JAR tool reference page for Windows").
4. That "JAR tool reference page" shows you the detailed documentation for the jar command. This is where you'll see the example "*jar umf Manifest.txt my_jar.jar*".  (Solaris/Linux doesn't use the "-" in front of the args such as "umf".

I used it (on Linux) to merge 2 custom Manifest files into the default Manifest and put it in my jar. I do it in a two-step process but would be interested to know of a one-step command to do this. (Using two m's to the jar command causes the second manifest to overwrite the first manifest - not merged.)(Remember each manifest file must end with a blank line.)

*Manifest.txt* contains "Name: " and "Implementation-Version: "

*Manifest.my_app.txt* contains "Main-Class: " and "Class-Path: "

The *default manifest* contains "Manifest-Version: " and "Created-By: "

```
jar cmf my_app.jar Manifest.txt my_main.class my_utils.class
jar umf Manifest.my_app.txt my_app.jar
```

After this, my *META-INF/MANIFEST.MF* contains all the fields from all 3 manifests. I expected them to be appended one to another but the fields are jumbled together. Maybe someone can tell how to order them or straight append. This is the order in which they appear in my current *META-INF/MANIFEST.MF*.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: my_app
Implementation-Version: 1.2.1
Class-Path: ...
Name: My App
Created-By: 1.6.0_20 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: My_App
```

I hope some of this is useful for you.

Comment: You know all the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/index.html) is online, right?